# Are there any text-to-video generators that are genuinely indistinguishable from a real recorded speech?

Tags: text-to-video

What is the best tool for speech to video generation? I’ve found a few but listening to demos from each (see links below), the sound and image is clearly AI-generated. I don't know if the mass market tech is there yet but i’m looking for something that’s basically indistinguishable from a real person giving a real speech.

These are the ones i tried and found underwhelming

- https://www.deepbrain.io/aistudios
- https://speechify.com/blog/text-speech-avatar/
- https://www.synthesia.io/

If anyone can suggest alternative tools to look into i'd appreciate any recommendations!

Answer (score 1):

OpenAI's text-to-speech is hard to distinguish from a real person giving a real speech (but we should do a blind test to quantify that). Demo and API: https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/text-to-speech

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for text-to-video (i.e. with avatars) not text-to-speech. This is the best i've found to date https://www.heygen.com/

Comment: @C.Robin Sorry I misread, I don't have any good pointers for realistic text-to-video. Last time I checked, the videos were clearly distinguishable from a real recorded video speeches. heygen looks pretty neat!

Comment: Sorry I misread, I don't have any good pointers for realistic text-to-video. Last time I checked, the videos were clearly distinguishable from a real recorded video speeches. heygen looks pretty neat!